# How to use PyCharm with Google compute engine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I have a compute engine instance running on Google cloud platform.

I would like to use the Python interpreter of the compute engine as a remote interpreter with Pycharm. This means that I would be using Pycharm on my local machine and running computations remotely.

Any clue on how to achieve this?

Comment: How are you trying to connect, did you follow this guide [1]? 

Please keep in mind that you have to open the port 22 in your Google Cloud VPC network[2]: 

[1] https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html 
[2] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Answer (score 12):

The following requires, as [James Hirschhorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349673/james-hirschorn) pointed out, the Professional verison of PyCharm.

1. Assign a public IP to the remote machine on GCP.
2. Run `gcloud compute config-ssh` to automatically add the VMs of your project to your `~/.ssh/config` or manually add the public IP of your VM to it. If you skipped step 1. then you have to run `gcloud compute config-ssh` every time you re-start the remote VM, because it always gets a new IP assigned. The `~/.ssh/config` gets populated with many entries in the following format:

   ```
   Host the-vm-host-name  # use this in PyCharm's Host field
       HostName 123.456.789.00  # the VM's IP address
   ```
3. Use the `Host` name of the remote you want to connect in your Deployment configuration in PyCharm
4. Add a remote interpreter: select the remote server from the drop-down (the one previously created) and point PyCharm to the executable `python` of your Python installation.
5. Done

Comment: How do you accomplish step 4? or 3 for that matter

Comment: ok damn it, I will update the post above to answer your question. Comments don't format well.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you need the Pycharm Ultimate Edition to support remote servers. If you have Ultimate, then you can follow [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to accomplish.
You need:

1. PyCharm Pro
2. Create and format SSH keys
3. Config your Compute Engine instance with the SSH keys
4. Configure PyCharm

You can follow [this](https://blog.doit-intl.com/remote-development-with-pycharm-and-google-cloud-1a8bdab3433f) tutorial that I wrote.

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial was great. I still struggle to actually run the scripts in GCP even if my pycharm says it uses remote python. I probably need to move the files I run somehow to my VM instance on GCP, I guess.

Comment: When you set it up correctly alongside the run configuration there should be a deployment set up. Read about how to deploy your code to the remote machine https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-deployment-in-product.html

Comment: Thanks gidutz. Yes, actually for some reason the directory path in my pycharm configuration had been done incorrectly in the automated setup. I had to go and manually correct the target path. Now it works like a dream. :)